# Win10 default tool for PDFs

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, pdf, file-association

I want to change the tool which is used in Win10 to open PDFs. It's no problem to select my prefered one in the file explorer and use it as default. But I noticed that Outlook doesn't care about this. When I do a double click on a PDF which is send by mail to me, Outlook uses Edge to open it.
How can I force Outlook to use my prefered PDF reader?

Comment: Open __Settings__ then __Apps__, in the left column you should find _Default Apps_ click on this. On the right hand pane, on the bottom of the links find and choose __Choose Default Apps By Filetype__

Comment: Thats what happens when I set the default app via file explorer. The default app for PDFs is set to my prefered tool, but Outlook still ignores it. I also rebooted the system several times since i changed the PDF reader. Nothing helps

Comment: If you have any experience with the Windows Registry find (in the Root section) .pdf and remove instance(s) of outlook. (You might have to trace a CLSID or two). If you do __Not__ have any experience with the Registry I would suggest you Do Not Touch It.

Comment: Make sure you restart outlook after you set the default app. If that does not do it, assign .PDF to open with any other program, such as notepad, then switch it back to what you want to use, then restart outlook and try again.

Comment: I restarted Outlook as well as the computer several times since i set the new default app

Answer (score 0):

One way of stopping Edge from hijacking the `.pdf` association is this way:

- Use `regedit` to navigate to the key

  ```
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\Repository\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_44.18362.449.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge\Capabilities\FileAssociations
  ```

  The package name may change with future releases, but it will always
  start with `Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge`.
- Note the value of the `.pdf` item, which is currently
  `AppXd4nrz8ff68srnhf9t5a8sbjyar1cr723`
- Navigate to the key
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\AppXd4nrz8ff68srnhf9t5a8sbjyar1cr723`
- Right-click the key `AppXd4nrz8ff68srnhf9t5a8sbjyar1cr723` and rename it,
  for example by appending an under-score (`_`)
  to be able to undo this in the future
- Use the Default Applications tool of Windows Control Panel to set the default
  application for PDF files.
- Reboot.

Comment: I followed the instrucktions, but edge still comes up when opening a pdf from Outlook. But the icon for the attached file in Outlook has changed. Prior it was a PDF icon, now it's the edge icon.

Comment: That shouldn't be happening. Try in *Control Panel > Programs and Features* to right-click Microsoft Office and choose *Change* to repair.

Comment: even after a reboot, outlook sttill opens PDFs via edge :-(

Comment: Microsoft keeps on sabotaging these things. Check Outlook *File > Options > Trust Centre > Trust Centre Settings > Attachment Handling > Attachment and Document Previewers* to see if you have a PDF preview handler that should be unchecked.

Comment: no, there are handlers form many/any MS-Office file types, but none for PDFs

Comment: (1) When you right-click a PDF file, Properties, General tab, what is the "Opens with" value? If this is Edge, click the Change button to modify. (2) If you are using Adobe Reader, try in the Help menu to click Repair installation. (3) Also try in Adobe *Edit > Preferences > General > Select As Default PDF Handler*.

Comment: PDF properties shows me, that it is set to open with SumatraPDF, my prefered reader. But Outlook still ignores it I also checkt SumatraPDF's settings, here is also checked to always open PDF documents with it, but Outlook still ignores this.

Comment: The Outlook guys really did it now. Last ideas: (1) Uninstall Office, reinstall and redo the above, (2) Try another PDF reader such as the excellent Foxit Reader, (3) Post a bug report with Microsoft via the Feedback Hub.

Comment: Thanks for your support, but I don't think I'll do this by now, that's to much to just change the PDF reader for now.